# Avoiding SSH timeout during remotely run Ant JUnit tests

Tags: ant, junit, ssh

I'm remotely running a JUnit test suite with Ant from my local machine to a remote server with a ~30 minute timeout. Running these JUnit tests with javac/java works fine since JUnit outputs a `.` or `E` after each test. This continuous output keeps the ssh connection alive for the ~9 hours that the test suite needs to run. However with Ant, there isn't any output until the test suite is completed, which kills the testing process way too early. I've tried several different result reporting methods (writing to a file, nearly all formatting options, etc).

My question is either:

How can I keep the SSH connection alive long enough for my test suite to finish? I don't have access/permission to alter any ssh connection settings and since the code is on the remote server I can't send anything to the server from my local machine before/during/after each test.

or

How can I set up Ant to print/echo some sort of output during each test? Using echo with Java's ProcessBuilder doesn't show up in Terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there a parameters to avoid a timeout ( which is probably server side ), but you should consider using the NOHUP command ( see [NOHUP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) ). This will allow you to launch your command and close your ssh session without stopping the command.

Alexis

Comment: This is perfect (I wish I knew about this earlier)! Initial tests show things working as expected, so now I'm going to run about an hour of tests to have a natural timeout occur. I'll accept your answer once I get that scenario working :)

Comment: Well after trying it several times I still get "nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'" and then after 30-45 minutes,
"Write failed: Broken pipe" and the file that Ant normally writes to was empty. I'll look deeper into nohup, since it seems to be exactly what I need.

Comment: The first message you get is normal: it just says it won't read stdin while running, and it will write stdout to 'nohup.out' file, which you should find in the path where you triggered the command. The _Broken pipe_ error is weird: are you sure this is link to the ssh connection?

Comment: Just to check: have you correctly launched your command in background? Have you check that your command  was really not running anymore? Maybe your ssh connection broke, but your process is sill running ( you said it's taking hours, so it could be reasonable that nothing was written after only 30mins? )

Comment: I believe I've correctly launched it (in this case `nohup ant &`), there is a [1] ###### displayed after running and then hitting enter allows me to enter in commands as normal. The nohup.out file is created and my ant script writes the header in the TEST-filename.java file. However there aren't any tests run or test results in either file when I exit the ssh connection right after running the nohup command. This is the same for running one test and running 20 tests.

Comment: Oh oh... While browsing the web i found this: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=34461 . It seems there might be some issues using nohup and ant together, while in your case it shouldn't be really problematic: could you trying running "nohup ant </dev/null &" ?

Comment: Hmm, I've actually gotten this to work with single test cases all of a sudden, which is a good and bad sign, since it might means the remote machine may be causing the problem. I'm going to talk to my system guys to see if there are some preexisting restrictions for programs using nohup (which knowing them is a distinct possibility). Thanks a ton for all your help!

Comment: You're welcome! But the bug report I mentioned earlier could still be the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that a firewall is killing the connection because it sees it's inactive, try setting ServerAliveInterval to 15 or so in your `~/.ssh/config`.

Alternatively, try running the test suite inside a Tmux or GNU Screen session. Your ssh connection will still break, but your tests will continue running and you'll be able to reconnect to them.